# Database schema and query for Google Reader-like application

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, many-to-many

For simplicity, let's assume we have a **single feed for all users**.

The feed is just a list of *articles*.
Each *user* is free to favorite a certain *article* or remove it from their personal view.

User deleting an article does not affect other users; each user has its own “view” of the feed.

#### Simple Approach

A naïve scheme I devised is below:

[image: user - article]

(Of course, in the real application there is more to user-article relationship than just hiding or starring.)

#### The Problem

It looks like **the link table entry should be created lazily, after the first change of options**.  Otherwise, when a new user signs up, or a new article pops up, we'd have to create a lot of empty link records, and also handle concurrency.

This means **selecting a list of articles for a certain user** is a query that combines:

- selecting all articles for which `ArticleUserLink` does not exist;
- selecting all articles for which `ArticleUserLink` exists and has `is_hidden = 0`.

> **Is `OR` the answer here, or is there a more effective database design / query to solve the problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using an inner query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Article a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ArticleUserLink WHERE article_id = a.id AND (is_hidden IS NULL OR is_hidden != 0))
```

Comment: That's assuming column is_hidden is NOT NULL and can only be 0/1.

Comment: why so? If is_hidden is null then subselect won't return any rows and the article will be displayed as it should.

Comment: Think it through (or test it). Your query in this form requires `is_hidden` to be defined `boolean NOT NULL` (or equivalent). If `is_hidden` can be `NULL` or `2`, the query will return rows, that shouldn't be returned.

Comment: Your amended version still doesn't cover `NULL` which may or may not be needed. The question does not define it. You could use the [MySQL specific operator <=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) for that - or a more standards-conforming statement like mine.

Comment: This worked fine for me. In my case, `is_hidden` *is* a `boolean NOT NULL` and this code is slightly easier to translate to Django so I went for it. Thanks to @Erwin too, for a more universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/left-join-optimization.html)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Article a
LEFT   JOIN ArticleUserLink ua ON (ua.article_id = a.id)
WHERE  a.user_id = insert_user_id_here
AND    (ua.is_hidden = 0) IS NOT FALSE
...
```

This way you get

- articles that **don't have** an associated entry in ArticleUserLink
- articles that **do have** an associated entry in ArticleUserLink **and** `ua.is_hidden = 0`

Comment: wont work, will still display article when user has is_hidden option set to 1

Comment: @socha23: Right, I had the logic reversed. Amended answer.